# Run script after desktop loads

Tags: shell-script, opensuse

I'm running a script that changes files and installs things and what not on a SUSE computer. One of the scripts that gets run with my script, reboots the computer and when the computer loads back up again I want my script to continue where it left off.

What I can't figure out is where to launch my script so that it will start **AFTER** the desktop has loaded back up (the SUSE computer is set to automatically log in as a specific user who isn't root).

I want my script to run in this fashion because I want the user to be able to see an output log as to what is happening before another script later on reboots the computer again.

**Edit:** Following the link given below: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=130344 I found out that the directory that is supposed to be where you put scripts specifically for my question is /home/user/.kde4/Autostart.

In my attempt to follow this I found that I do not have a .kde4 directory, but I do have a .kde directory. I decided this was probably the same thing and investigated finding that .kde does have Autostart. So I placed my script in there.

This resulted in my script being opened by KWrite (just the basic text editor) when my desktop loads. But the script itself doesn't get run.

I created a new directory, .kde4 with Autostart in it to place my script hoping that this would solve the problem. No luck, though, as my script doesn't even get opened in KWrite in this situation.

**Edit2:** I changed the permission on my script `chmod 777 script` and now it starts up. It's in my home/user/.kde/Autostart directory.

Comment: KDE or GNOME desktop?

Comment: How do I check that? I'm pretty sure it's KDE, but I want to be certain.

Comment: Does this return any results? `ps -eaf|grep gnome-session
`

Comment: It only returns one line. `[user] 3576 3442 0 19:27 pts/1  00:00:00 grep gnome-session`

Comment: So you're using KDE then. I'd start with this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=130344

Comment: Well I tried putting my script $HOME/.kde/Autostart/ but all that happens is the file gets opened in KWrite. I found another script already there with the .Autostart extension so I put my script with both that extension and .sh, neither worked.

Comment: @slm You pretty much answered my question first, but you didn't give an answer so I can't mark it as correct.

Comment: don't worry about it, glad you got your issue resolved is my primary concern. 8-). BTW you can back the permissions off and make it `chmod 755 ...`.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but permissions don't specifically matter to me all that much since I'm going to have my script delete itself when it's done.

Comment: Sure, just wasn't sure if you were aware or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using KDE you should go to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Autostart, click Add Script button, add you script there and set it to run at Startup.

From command line you could create a symlink in the following folder /home/username/.kde4/Autostart like this:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/your/script /home/username/.kde4/Autostart/script
```

Comment: I don't want to add the script with System Settings (which I can't find anyway) because it defeats the purpose of just clicking the script and having it do everything for me. I tried using the command line option you gave, but I still get the same result that the script just gets opened in KWrite. I don't have a .kde4 directory, just a .kde folder. I tried creating a .kde4 directory with Autostart in it and placed the script in there just like your example, but then nothing happened, not even the script being loaded in KWrite.

Comment: If you have only .kde directory then put the script there in /home/username/.kde/Autostart and make sure the script is executable by running chmod +x /path/to/script